# Atualizar uma coluna do sql de todos os registros

Tags: mysql, sql-server

vou tentar ser o mais especifico possível, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço bastante.

Preciso saber como faço para alterar uma informação em uma coluna de todos os registros do banco de dados.

Por exemplo: Tenho o banco de dados com a tabela "Users" e nesta tabela existe uma coluna chamada "Conta". Nesta coluna tem a informação "Inativo" e preciso mudar para "Ativo", porém de todos os registros de uma única vez.
É possível fazer isto? Estou usando o PhpMyAdmin

Comment: sim, é só você fazer o UPDATE sem o WHERE, assim vai atualizar a tabela toda, para ajudar com o sql em si edite a sua pergunta e inclua a estrutura da tabela

Comment: Perfeito! Faço através do PHP ou seu consigo fazer diretamente no SQL?

Comment: Você pode fazer diretamente pelo SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas,

Você pode fazer um update do campo desejado sem a clausula where ou você pode fazer conforme o código abaixo, onde você terá o efeito desejado atualizando apenas os registros que precisa:

```
update Users set Conta = 'Ativo' where Conta = 'Inativo';
```

Comment: Top! Obg Sérgio Lopes

Answer (score -2):

Usei este codigo e funcionou: [Demostracao da linha de comando no console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqQ84.jpg)`update users set conta = "Activo"`